# Как получить нужный класс в jQuery если они одинаковы и их много?

Tags: html, jquery

Есть список сообщений из базы данных, у каждого сообщения есть скрытое поле с классом, в котором хранится айди этого сообщения. Так как этих классов много я не знаю как обратиться к нужному в jquery?

Comment: В зависимости от разметки - это будет всегда по-разному. Можно использовать find, closest, `>`, children, да всё что угодно. Просто открыть доки jquery и прочитать про селекторы

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу html пожалуйста, тогда будет проще понять, в чём проблема. И что мешает хранить айдишники в id, а не в class?